# Save Elements of Mean() into two lists

Tags: r, mosaic

When entered

```
mean(views ~ Month, data=dataset)
```

results

[[image: ]R Output[1]]

How do I save Months into one list, and values into another? Eventually I will do a regressional analysis

Comment: Can you please give us a data example so we can make it reproducible? I guess this problem depends on the classes.

Comment: Where does your function `mean` come from? `base::mean` does not have a formula interface. Also, if that is the result you have, to get the `Months` maybe `names(result)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas If I do this (results <- mean(views~Month, data=dataset), and then do names(results), then I do get the names! That's great! Now I just need the values

Comment: @Neoromanzer it probably does. If we create a simple data frame where "boy" mean is 10, and "girl" mean is 15, I wanna created 2 list. 1 would be "boy", "girl", and the other [10,15]

Comment: Dont use the rstudio tag for questions which are plain R language questions.

Comment: To get the values maybe `unname(results)` or `as.numeric(results)`.

Comment: This question/answer is useful to no one but you unless you reveal where you got your `mean` function.

Comment: @RichScriven I believe it's from the `mosaic` package

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `mean` function OP's referring to comes from the `mosaic` package. If that is the case, there is a `.format="table"` argument to output the `mean` per group into a well-formatted `data.frame`:

```
library(mosaic)

mean(cyl ~ gear, data = mtcars, .format = "table")
```

**Result:**

```
  gear     mean
1    3 7.466667
2    4 4.666667
3    5        6
```

From `?mean` (after loading `mosaic`):

> wrap in data.frame() to auto-convert awkward variable names

So in OP's case, the safest would be to write:

```
means_E_T = data.frame(mean(U_E ~ E_T, data = etr, .format = "table"))
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias amigo!

Comment: @AndrewWolfe If this answers your question, do consider accepting it by clicking on the grey check mark under the downvote button:)